# Why is a variable passed to the su command, but not an array from the same scope?

Tags: bash, shell, quoting

In the example below, why does `$var` get passed to the `su` in the start function, but not the array `modules` ?

```
#!/bin/bash
var=cat
modules=(
one
two
three
four
)

start() {
    su gleventh -c "for i in ${modules[@]}; do echo -- $i -- $var;  done"
}

$1

echo "out of function"
for i in ${modules[@]}; do echo -- $i -- $var;  done
```

The script above returns:

```
$ sudo ./test.sh start
-- -- cat
-- -- cat
-- -- cat
-- -- cat
out of function
-- one -- cat
-- two -- cat
-- three -- cat
-- four -- cat
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem was that since the su statement was in double quotes, the variables were all expanded before the su command was called, which means $var becomes "cat" but $i becomes "" since it was not defined.  Bash doesn't know that it was supposed to be an iterator variable, it just expands it to a NULL string.  The answer is to escape that "$" like so:

```
#!/bin/bash
var=cat
modules=(
one
two
three
four
)

start() {
    su gleventh -c "for i in ${modules[@]}; do echo -- \$i -- $var;  done"
}

$1

echo "out of function"
for i in ${modules[@]}; do echo -- $i -- $var;  done
```

Comment: Strange. I'm getting `two: -c: line X: syntax error: unexpected end of file`

Comment: You copied it verbatim? (and changed the gleventh to a valid user)

Comment: Yes. `BASH_VERSION=4.2.53(1)-release`, OpenSUSE 13.1.

Comment: My guess is the encoding in the quotes is different from whatever you used to edit with.  I would go back and manually replace all of the double quotes by hand and run it again.

Comment: Pardon? `${var[@]}` should do word splitting according to the documentation (see `man bash`).

Comment: I was saying if you copied and pasted from this web page to your editor or terminal, perhaps there was an issue with the encoding of the double quotes, and they were copied as another character.  I have seen quotes be translated to backticks when copying into the Terminal from certain applications.

Comment: No. When piped to `xxd`, the double quotes correspond to `22` in hex.

Answer (score 1):

The special parameter `${array[@]}` in double quotes causes word splitting if the array has more than one member:

```
$ for word in "for i in ${arr[@]} ; do" ; do echo "$word" ; done
for i in a
b
c ; do
```

If your modules' names don't contain spaces, you can have more luck using the `*` subscript:

```
$ for word in "for i in ${arr[*]} ; do" ; do echo "$word" ; done
for i in a b c ; do
```

Comment: The elements of the array are "one two three four" no spaces.  Using ${ [*]} didn't make any difference, I see no element of the array when using su.

Comment: @GreggLeventhal: Did you replace the `@` in double quotes, right?

Comment: I figured it out, the answer for me was to put the iterator variable "$i" with an escape like "\$i"

Comment: The problem was that $i was being evaluated before the su command was run, so instead of being the iterator variable in the su statement, it had already evaluated to a blank string since $i was not defined.

Comment: @GreggLeventhal: You're right. Does it work with a `@`, though?

Comment: Yes, if I escape the iterator variable, it works fine with [@].  I always use @ in arrays, I don't use * ever.

Comment: `su` is probably clever enough to glue the parts back together.